# Cryptic Setka - Complete grid using clues and sudoku-style logic

Tags: logical-deduction, wordplay, cryptic-clues

This is a Setka puzzle; you can find more (along with a more detailed explanation of the rules) at our website, linked from this user's profile.

How to play Setka, the short version:

Answer each clue using only Puzzle Letters and vowels.

Clue answers, minus vowels and duplicate letters, go in the corresponding boxes in the grid. Only Puzzle Letters go in the grid!

Puzzle Letters can be entered forward/backward/up/down/L-shape, but not jumbled. They also cannot repeat in a row or column.

This puzzle has the same Setka rules you know and love, with one exception: the clue answers do not relate to something cryptic or the concept of cryptic. Instead, each clue is a word puzzle in and of itself.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is

> [image]
>
>  **1 COCKSURE** – rooster's name + certain
>  **2 POKER** – fire iron and card game
>  **3 YURT** – y(og)urt without zero gravity, a round house
>  **4 POSE** ??  – *unsure why*
>  **5 STYE** – sty + e(ast)
>  **6 SCRIPT** – (thanks to @JMP) for a play, and handwriting
>  **7 TACO** – anagram of coat
>  **8** – *unsolved* must make PT or TP
>  **9 CAKE** – (thanks to @JMP) form of yellow coke (*unsure about Muse connection*)
>  **10 PAY** – also anagram of yap
>  **11 CRACK** – sound of whip, decipher
>  **12 YETI** – (thanks to @JMP) has big feet
>  **13 RACK** – (thanks to @JMP) where clothes are hung, implement of torture
>  **14 SAPPY** – play on words
>  **15 SEEKER** – see + Ker(r)
>  **16 PUTTY** – (thanks to @JMP) putt + whY
>  **17 EYE** – sounds like aye, birds-eye view from high
>  **18 KICK** – (thanks to @JMP) aim for goal, do something for kicks
>
>  Fitting them into the grid:
>  **3** is YRT or TRY so the R of **1** CKSR must go on row 2
>  **2** is PKR or RKP but again, the R of **3** YRT means it must be RKP
>  **10** is PY or YP but that means that **3** must be YRT
>  **7** is TC or CT but **3** YRT means it must be TC
>  **15** is SKR or RKS but the R of **11** CRK means it must be SKR
>  **14** is SPY or YPS but the S of **15** SKR means it must be YPS
>  **11** is CRK or KRC but the K of **1** CKSR means it must be KRC
>
>   which gave (before the additions from @JMP)
>
>  [image]
>
>  The rest of the cells could be completed from Sudoku logic.

Comment: Some of the ones you missed: https://rot13.com/ 6. FPEVCG?, 12. LRGVF - cyheny bs ovt sbbg, 13. ENPX - qqsa, 16. CHGGL - chgg+l, 18. XVPX - xvpxf=guevyyf

Comment: 9 is PNYR and uggcf://ra.jvxvcrqvn.bet/jvxv/Lryybjpnxr

Comment: @JMP thanks, they all match with the grid, assuming rot13(lbh zrnag PNXR abg PNYR) and I updated the answer with credit.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urania

Comment: Great job on the puzzle.

Clue 4 - Do it softly in order to flex the hips. Answer is PSOAS
  - Soft is P (piano in music, abbreviated as p.)
  - “in order to” is “so as”
  - Psoas is a hip flexor muscle

Clue 8 - Mystery writer par excellence–the opposite of drab! Answer is POET

Clue 9 - “Yellowcake” is also called Urania, who is one of the Muses.

You can find more puzzles at our website, linked in our profile - they're all free to play. Thanks!